# AsyncTasks are not running in parallel

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to download a file with a progress bar in the UI updated and while downloading that I can want to remove an item in a grid found in the same activity.

What I do is as follows :

```
new FileDownloadTask(Req,item,frag.getActivity(),progUpdate).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

and while download is running I do :

```
new DeleteItemTask(item,progUpdate).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

The second task still executed serially after the first one is completed.

(I use API Level 14 )

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/) for more info on the subject

Comment: Looks like you have them setup to use parallel execution API 14+ and specifying the executor. How do you know they are executing serially? What do these Tasks do? It's possibly you accidentally made them serial based on their internals. Can you share that code?

Comment: Sorry all, It's my problem. There was another (third) asynctask that's not configured to be parallel and it was causing this problem.